# The distributive dot product of the curls of two vector fields

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

I am trying to prove that the integral in three dimensions of dot product (F, curl G) is equal to the integral of dot product $(G, \operatorname{curl} F)$ on a domain $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is bounded by a closed surface $S$. The surface normal $n$ of $S$ is a linear combination of $F$ and $G$ (two continuously differentiable vector fields).

Thus I think I should first rewrite for the $(S,n)$ with the divergence theorem and use the distributive property of the dot product - using the linear combination fact for the surface normal - and write:
$$
\iiint \limits_D   (F, \operatorname{curl} G) \text{d}V = \iint \limits_S  (aF,\operatorname{curl} G) \text{d}A + \iint \limits_S  (bG,\operatorname{curl}G) \text{d}A \\
\iiint \limits_D  (G, \operatorname{curl} F) \text{d}V = \iint \limits_S  (aF,\operatorname{curl} F) \text{d}A + \iint \limits_S  (bG,\operatorname{curl} F) \text{d}A
$$
I feel like I should be able to set some things equal to each other here, but I get stuck.
Also, I am wondering if I am switching in the right way between the domain and the surface. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The D and S should be under the integral sign of course

Comment: I cannot understand this at all. Your $dt$ I assume  is $dV$ on the left and (only a surface integral, not triple integral) $d\sigma$ in the right. Your $D$ and $S$ need to be subscripts to the integrals. Please edit and state correctly exactly what you are trying to prove. It doesn’t look right so far. You need the divergence theorem, not Stokes’s Theorem.

Comment: Thank you Ted, you are absolutely right, I implemented your edits!
I will attribute the way I rewrote it to the divergence theorem, I see that I named the wrong theorem. I am still stuck however as to why the integrals are equal in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector identity you need is this: For $C^1$ vector fields $\vec F$ and $\vec G$ on $\Bbb R^3$, we have
$$\text{div}(\vec F\times\vec G) = (\text{curl}\,\vec F,\vec G) - (\vec F,\text{curl}\,G).$$
Then the Divergence Theorem tells us that
$$\iiint_V \text{div}(\vec F\times\vec G)\,dV = \iint_S (\vec F\times\vec G,\vec n)\,dS,$$
where $\vec n$ is the unit outward-pointing normal to $S=\partial V$.
Now, if you *assume* that at each point of $S$, $\vec n$ is a linear combination of $\vec F$ and $\vec G$, then the integrand on the right-hand side vanishes. This gives what I believe is the result you were trying to establish.

Comment: This will solve it I think! One final question to see if I understand it: Do you mean that the right-side becomes 0, thus (curl F,G) = (F, curl G) ?

Comment: The integrals are equal. Substitute my first displayed equation in the second.